# How to add white space between two strings

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have an API to be called form my MVC project. I use this line to add generated token to the request -> `request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);`
But when I run a debugger, It shows me Bearer + token without any space. I think this is the reason why I can't be authorized to reach the API. I tried `string.PadRight`, `string.Format` But none of them worked

Comment: "But when I run a debugger" - on the client or the server?

Comment: Client and Server both are in the same solution, And I set the solution to start both of them at the same time. I ran debugger on MVC project as client

Comment: And where exactly did you see the space removed?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an interpolated string:

`request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {accessToken}");`

If that doesn't work, it is probably because `HttpHeaders.Add(String name, String value)` parses and validates `value`. Part of that parsing may be to remove whitespace.